# Rewrite new url and block old url in nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a local folder `/bar`, and I want to be able access via `http://www.example.com/foo`.

So I have the config like

```
rewrite  ^/foo/(.*)$ /bar/$1 last;
```

At the same time, I want to **block** public access to the real url `/bar`,

Then I add the config like

```
location ~* ^/bar{ return 404; }
```

But when I add this url into the config, the 1st config above not work, now both return `404`

Anything I should fix in order to make the rewrite work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the "old" location as `internal` :

```
location /bar {
  internal;
  # your /bar location directives
}
```

Nginx processes "internal" locations only when they happen as a result of `error_page`, `rewrite`, `X-Accel-Redirect` or SSI requests (see the full list in [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal)), otherwise it replies 404.